# Ruby - less expensive way for chained ActiveRecord queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

What I have is currently working, but seems to be very expensive, any ideas on making it less expensive would be great!

A `User` has many `Plans`, which has many `PlanDates`. Each `PlanDates` has a certain recipe denoted by a `recipe_id` attribute. Each `Plan` has a `meal_type` attribute which is either `Meat`, `Vegetarian`, or `Choice`, the latter means mixed. Each `Recipe` has a `type_of_meal` attribute that is either `Meat` or `Vegetarian`. Each `Recipe` also has a friendly `name` attribute.

For a given PlanDate, I need to build an `options_for_select` in the following format:

```
[ [recipe_id, "recipe_name"], [recipe_id, "recipe_name"] ... ]
```

The options:

- must remove all the `recipe_ids` that have previously been given to the User (regardless of Plan)
- must remove all the `recipe_ids` with a type mismatch (i.e., if a Plan has `Meat` designated, the options must not have any `Vegetarian` `recipe_ids`), certainly this is not true if the Plan has `Choice` designated

Here's the code I currently have:

```
# builds an array of all the recipe_ids that have been given to this User on some PlanDate on some Plan
recipes_used_before_for_this_user = PlanDate.select { |pd| pd.plan.user.id == user_id }.map { |pd| pd.recipe_id }

# narrows down the world of recipes to those that do NOT have an id of a recipe_used_before_for_this_user
recipes_not_used_before = Recipe.select { |r| (recipes_used_before_for_this_user.include? r.id) == false }

# going forward, let's assume current_pd = the PlanDate object in question

if current_pd.plan.meal_type == "Choice"
   # easiest: if the meal_type is "Choice" then we just take the recipes_not_used_before and map them into the appropriate format
   recipe_choices_array = recipes_not_used_before.map { |r| [ r.id, r.name ] }
else
   # if the plan has a "Meat" or "Vegetarian" specification, we need to first narrow the recipes_not_used_before down by the right type and then map into the appropriate format
   recipe_choices_array = recipes_not_used_before.select { |r| r.type_of_meal == potential_pd.first.plan.meal_type }.map { |r| [ r.id, r.name ] }
end
```

Again, working, but I have a lot of PlanDates and a lot of Recipes, so if there is any way to streamline even further, would love your ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick note - often you have to drop by to straight sql for this sort of stuff.  You might be able to use arel but with some nasty subselects.  I'll pop back by later and you don't have a reasonable answer I'll answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're experiencing expensive queries is because you're not actually using ActiveRecord's query interface, or even SQL to narrow your query, but instead are loading the entire dataset into Ruby memory objects and then looping over the result in Ruby.

I suspect that if you inspect your logfiles you'll see something like this:

```
>> PlanDate.select{ |pd| pd.plan.user.id == user_id }.map { |pd| pd.recipe_id }
  PlanDate Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "plan_dates".* FROM "plan_dates"
=> [#<PlanDate....
```

What you want to do is to use ActiveRecord's query interface to build the query, something like this:

```
PlanDate.includes(plan: [:user]).where("plan.user_id == ?", :user_id).pluck('recipe_id')
```

What that does is first: [Specify relationships to be included in the result set](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes), then [specify the where conditions](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where) of your SQL query, and finally pull out the recipe ids using [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck).

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html for more info.